# How retrieve the value (in one line using jquery) when user clicks the text box of nth row and nth column

Tags: jquery

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addRow()">Add  
 Product</button></div>
<table id="dataTable" class="table product">
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>

<script>
function addRow()
{
   var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="product_id[]"></td> 
   <td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td><td><input type="text" 
   name="price[]"></td></tr>');
   jQuery('table.product-details tbody').append(newRow);
}
</script>
```

In above code when a user clicks the button, the above function will be executed.So that tables(row and column) are generated dynamically.

In this case,there are 'n' number of rows and 'n' number of columns when user clicks the particular `textbox` i want to retrieve that corresponding value only without using `for loop`, `eq()` method and `onClick` event.
For Eg: If user click the 3rd row 2nd column textbox in table retrieve that 3rd row 2nd column value only.

Comment: From multiple row fetch the current row dropdown value in table.How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

try this code

Use `onclick` function on `input` and using this get input `value or attributes`

```js
function addRow() {

  var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="product_id[]" onclick="fun(this)"></td><td><input type = "text" name = "description[]" onclick="fun(this)"></td><td><input type="text" name = "price[]" onclick="fun(this)"> </td></tr> ');
  jQuery('table#dataTable tbody').append(newRow);
}

function fun(t) {
  alert(jQuery(t).val());
  alert(jQuery(t).attr('name'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="addRow()">Add  
 Product</button></div>
<table id="dataTable" class="table product">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```